# How to store CLPlacemark address data in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, core-location

I've been thinking what's the best way to store CLPlacemark data (e.g. Thoroughfare, Locality, Country etc.). There is quite a number of them and I'm currently storing them individually as strings in Core Data but it is quite cumbersome.

Perhaps I should instead store as transformable CLPlacemark instead? Any other way to efficiently and quickly store a whole bunch of key-value pairs?

Comment: transformable would be better, u can also one more entity for CLPlacemark, and relate it were ever it require..

Comment: How would the transformer for CLPlacemark look? I've done it for images, which I transform to NSData and get it back.

Comment: Ah nevermind, seems like CLPlacemark conforms to NSCoding so no transformer is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up storing CLPlacemark as a transformable type in Core Data. Saved a lot of headache doing it this way, and since CLPlacemark is NSCoding compatible no transformer is required, very easy.

Comment: Wow I didn't even know there was such a thing as `transformable` in Core Data. Glad I googled 'CLPlacemark Core Data' ;-) Will definitely read into that.